# Reset (hyperlink) in Excel without Macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have single spreadsheet with multiple sheets with varios calculations in them. What I want is to create a RESET button (or hyperlink) using which I can reset all the values back to default!

Howevere I have restricted myself not to use Macros because of security issues. Is there a way possible to create such a RESET button which when clicked will:
 - Clear specific cells in sheet!
 - Set spcific cells to their default values in sheet!

Comment: Is this even possible???

Comment: In case VBA is restricted the only way to do that is to make a copy of initial file and reopen it as a reset.

Comment: as @Peter L suggests, never save over the original. Perhaps make it read-only by default

Answer (score 0):

So you can just make a cell that is just used for your 'Reset' and have it say yes/no to use the below example.  You can leave the 'overwrite' column blank and it will pick up the original calculation either way.  This is pretty hacky but if you are going to stay away from vba this is probably your best shot.  I would suggest doing some validation and NameRanges to keep it as clean as possible because if you add complexity to it you may run into trouble.  Basically to clear the cells just keep the 'Overwrite' in the same column and wipe them out when you change reset from 'no' to 'yes'.

I can't post images yet but the instructions below should work (reputation please!)

```
A1 = 'Reset'
A2 = yes/no [validation]
A4 = a
A5 = 1
B4 = b
B5 = 2
C4 = 'Original Result'
C5 = A5 + B5
D4 = 'Overwrite'
D5 = whatever formula/entry you want to overwrite your original calculation
E4 = 'Result'
E5 = =IF(A2="yes",C5,IF(D5="",C5,D5))
```